# Nodejs and user authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication

I have created a simple user authentication for my nodejs app, it takes posted username and password and compares these against a database (encrypted of course). If it seems to match the server generates a token to be saved in the database(IP also gets saved) and sends this back. Client stores the token in a cookie and for every action which requires the user to be authenticated, the client sends the token to the server which looks if it exists in the database and that the IP matches, else you have to log in again.

I read over and over again that you should never create your own authentication system if you do not know what you are doing and that you should use an existing one. But my little system, is it good enough or is there something else I should think about? I run it over SSL of course.

Comment: You mean you store the password in a reversible way ? Then it's bad. You should at least hash.

Comment: Using sha256? that's the only secure way.